# XJC: Generate subpackages for complexTypes

Tags: java, ant, jaxb, xsd, xjc

is it Possible to generate extra subpackages per complexType when generating Javaclasses with XJC2Task?

I have a problem generating from a xsd where i have a complexType named Traveller which has an element named "ElementNumber".

But also a single complexType named TravellerElementNumber.

When generating i recieve the Error "Two declarations cause a collision in the ObjectFactory class.

Is there any way to fix this issue without changing the xsd?

Best Regards,

Sti

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't generate subpackages for complex types OOTB.

Yes, you can fix it without changing the schema. Use the `jaxb:factoryMethod` binding element.

[Example](https://github.com/highsource/ogc-schemas/blob/master/gml/3.1.1/src/main/resources/binding.xjb#L265):

```
<jaxb:bindings version="1.0" xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb" 
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

    <jaxb:bindings 
        schemaLocation="ogc/gml/3.1.1/base/feature.xsd" 
        node="/xs:schema">
        <jaxb:bindings node="xs:element[@name='_FeatureCollection']">
            <jaxb:factoryMethod name="AFeatureCollectionElement"/>
        </jaxb:bindings>
    </jaxb:bindings>
</jaxb:bindings>
```

You have to point the binding to one of the elements where you have the conflict. Don't forget to include the bindings file (see [this example](https://github.com/highsource/jaxb2-basics/blob/master/samples/po/project-build.xml#L78-L80)).

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But now im getting  [ERROR] compiler was unable to honor this factoryMethod customization. It is attached to a wrong place, or its inconsistent with other bindings.

Any Idea?

Comment: Well, attach it to the *right* place then. I just don't think I'm telepathic enough to guess where your mistake is without seeing any of your code. I just know `jaxb:factoryMethod` works and this is the answer to your question.

Comment: Thanks for your help! After including the newest jaxb libs it worked like a charm!